# Retrieve records of recently modified files among duplicates in same folder

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

Table

```
col1        col1        col3
filepath1   filename1   modified date1
filepath1   filename1   modified date1
filepath1   filename1   modified date2  <- latest in duplicates in col1
filepath1   filename2   modified date3
filepath1   filename3   modified date4

filepath2   filename2   modified date3  <- latest in duplicates in col1
filepath2   filename2   modified date1
filepath2   filename2   modified date2
filepath2   filename3   modified date1

filepath3   filename3   modified date1
filepath3   filename1   modified date1
filepath3   filename2   modified date1
filepath3   filename3   modified date2  <- latest in duplicates in col1
filepath3   filename4   modified date1
```

Output:

```
filepath1   filename1   modified date2
filepath2   filename2   modified date3
filepath3   filename3   modified date2
```

---

I want to retrieve those records of latest duplicate files in same folder.

I was thinking to do as below, but not clear on how it will give correct result.

```
string duptbl = SELECT * FROM mytable
INNER JOIN(
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM mytable
GROUP BY fname
HAVING COUNT(id) >1
)temp ON mytable.fname = temp.fname;
```

Comment: Please [format the data](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) in your question in such a way that it is legible. Correcting your sample data so that it contains the columns used in your query attempt (`fname`, `id`) would be helpful. Your current query attempt is [non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html#:~:text=the%20values%20chosen%20are%20nondeterministic) (columns in projection not functionally dependent on GROUP BY and not in aggregate functions) and relies on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY being disabled, which it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the desired output is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (fpath, fname, modified) IN (
    SELECT fpath, fname, MAX(modified)
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY fpath, fname
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Output:

| fpath | fname | modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| filepath1 | filename1 | 2024-02-02 |
| filepath2 | filename2 | 2024-02-03 |
| filepath3 | filename3 | 2024-02-02 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nFHI3Sxm).

Note that if there are multiple rows with the same `fpath`, `fname` and `modified` values then they will all be returned.